# Magento saves a wrong order total amount and put the order in Subspected Fraud

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal-pro, suspected-fraud

I've a problem in the order resume when a user is applying a discount code.

[image: The total amound is wrong]

In fact the subtotal is 68 + 8 (shipment) and - 6.80 (discount code) = €69.2 and not €76.0 like what's written in the page.

The payment is made with paypal and the total is correct (€69.2) but magento is putting the order in **Subspected Fraud** - *IPN "Completed". Order is suspended as its capture amount 69,20 € is suspected to be fraudulent.*

Actually the problem is happening with any discount code.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: discount code means coupon code or any custom discount programmatically ?

Comment: Coupon code man, sorry

Comment: @GopalPatel no ideas?

Comment: Such issue arise after applying  programmatically custom discount. As you have applied coupon then must be you have change core code of coupon or in observer  you have change the quote.

Comment: @GopalPatel the problem is that I've not changed anything in the source code of magento...

Comment: put your discount calculation code for complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

Are you by any chance running this on PHP7?

If so, you might be looking at error due to order in which totals are calculated. If so, please refer to [this](https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7/commit/5f8d3edb5bd7a04f8951e397eebbeba2c30b77ff).

Answer (score 0):

Check the setting :

```
Admin->System->Configuration->Sales->Tax->Calculation Setting->Tax Calculation Method Based On
```

Change this setting as on `Total`.

Also I think you are not updating `grand total` and `base grand total` when applying custom discount programmatically.

You have to update these 2 values when calculating discount.

Comment: "Tax Calculation Method Based On" was already "Total". I don't know where to find the grand total and base grand total options. Otherwise I tried to set "Enable Cross Border Trade" on Yes but it still doesn't change.

Comment: @GiacomoTorricelli, Please put your discount calculation code in your question, then only I can help you.

Comment: Actually I'm using the IWD One Page checkout https://www.iwdagency.com/extensions/one-step-page-checkout.html

Comment: @GiacomoTorricelli, IWD is just a checkout process. Its not calculating discount. How you are offering discount on any order ?

Comment: Yes IWD is the checkout extension but it integrate the discount code textbox in that page so I think it's in their code the coupon management.  I'm generating coupons with Shopping Cart Price Rules obv.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

Replace the following in Mage_Paypal_Model_Hostedpro_Request

```
protected function _getOrderData(Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order)

     {
                $request = array(
                    'subtotal'      => $this->_formatPrice($order->getBaseSubtotal()),
                    'tax'           => $this->_formatPrice($order->getBaseTaxAmount()),
                    'shipping'      => $this->_formatPrice($order->getBaseShippingAmount()),
                    'invoice'       => $order->getIncrementId(),
                    'address_override' => 'true',
                    'currency_code'    => $order->getBaseCurrencyCode(),
                    'buyer_email'      => $order->getCustomerEmail(),
                    'discount'         => $this->_formatPrice(
                        $order->getBaseGiftCardsAmount()
                        + abs($order->getBaseDiscountAmount())
                        + $order->getBaseCustomerBalanceAmount()
                    ),
                );
```

with this

```
protected function _getOrderData(Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order)
    {
        $request = array(
            'subtotal'      => $this->_formatPrice($order->getBaseGrandTotal()),
            'invoice'       => $order->getIncrementId(),
            'address_override' => 'true',
            'currency_code'    => $order->getBaseCurrencyCode(),
            'buyer_email'      => $order->getCustomerEmail(),
            ),
        );
```